# Openshift - Error adding jenkins app to a project

Tags: jenkins, command-line-interface, openshift, redhat

I'm currently taking a Red Hat course on OpenShift fundamentals. At some point, it asks me to create a project and then to add a jenkins-persistance app to it. The first image was provided by the course, the second is my interface.
I tried to do the same via Web Console (UI) and I saw an over-quota error, it said that I got 30 secrets out of 30. but I don't know what that means.

#### Expectation:

[image: course screenshot]

#### Reality:

[image: my screenshot]

Comment: First check the CLI and server's versions using `oc version`, is it same version ?

Comment: oc v3.11.0+0cbc58b
kubernetes v1.11.0+d4cacc0
features: Basic-Auth SSPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://master.na39.openshift.opentlc.com:443
openshift v3.9.40
kubernetes v1.9.1+a0ce1bc657

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your information.

AFAIK, The `OpenShift` is only available within a major version are forward and backward compatible across one minor version. Your OpenShift Cluster is `v3.9.40`, but the CLI is `v3.11.xxx`, it's not available. Try to use the same version CLI.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that

Comment: It should works, but you can face some issues with that- newer cluster, older client > ok, you can be missing some functions;  older cluster, newer client- you can use some functions, which cluster doesnt know, can fail. So best solution is to have same oc version as the cluster is :).

Comment: @AgustínClemente That's great !